# Why to use new to initialize something in JAVA?

Tags: java

Why do we use this syntax in JAVA

```
FreshJuice juice = new FreshJuice();
```

instead of just

```
FreshJuice juice;
```

Comment: Because a programmer should have control over how and when an Object is initialized.

Comment: How would you know what type it’s to be otherwise?

Comment: I kinda get you, can you be more explicit?

Comment: `FreshJuice juice;` just declares *variable*. We don't always want to assign value to it at time of declaration. Sometimes we want to do it in other places, like in `try` section, or `if` branch (when we need to decide what value to assign). Assigning there by default new value would be waste of time when know we will not use it and assign different one. Also how should such default value look like? Lets say we have `File path`, what should such `path` hold?

Answer (score 2):

For many reasons, including:

- There is no guarantee that `FreshJuice` will be a concrete class; it can be an interface or an abstract class instead.
- You might not have a default constructor available.
- You might not have any constructor available at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to create an object before initializing it. 
When you call `new FreshJuice();` it firsts allocates memory for the object on heap, and then initializes it.(with default values in this case as provided in corresponding default constructor)

Comment: That doesn't mean anything.. why can't you initialize before creating?

Comment: Initialization means storing some value in an object. But before you do that, you must have some memory allocated for the object where that value can be stored.

Comment: As an analogy, suppose you need to build a house. However before you can build that lavish house of yours, you need to find a piece of land where you'll be building your house.

Comment: I get it Ashu :)